# C# Schema validation returns false success

Tags: c#, xml, validation

I've been working on this project that should allow the user to point to an XML file and that file to be validated against a XML schema. 
Nothing "complicated" so far.

I tested it against a proper XML - validation succeeded.
Added a node to the XML - validation failed.

Everything looked perfect, until I fed it a completely unrelated xml file.
One that I had in my temp folded, extracted from the scheduled task manager long ago.
... and the validation succeeded.

I still cannot understand "WHY".
The schema has a targetnamespace, which is not present in the "random" xml.
...and the structure is nothing alike. 
Can anyone explain how the validation process actually go and why it's succeeded in this scenario?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema;

namespace XMLtoXSDValidation
{
    class clsXMLManage
    {
        string filepath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    public bool ValidateSchema(string path)
    {
        try
        {


            string schemaPath = Path.Combine(filepath, "XMLSchema1.xsd");

            XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            settings.Schemas.Add("XMLtoXSDValidation", schemaPath);
            settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path, settings);

            XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
            document.Load(reader);



            ValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new ValidationEventHandler(ValidationEventHandler);
            document.Validate(eventHandler);

            return true;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", ex.Message);
            return false;
        }


    }


    static void ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
    {

        switch (e.Severity)
        {
            case XmlSeverityType.Error:
                Console.WriteLine("Error: {0}", e.Message);


                break;
            case XmlSeverityType.Warning:
                Console.WriteLine("Warning {0}", e.Message);


                break;
        }


    }

}}
```

Here is the schema:

```
    <xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="XMLtoXSDValidation" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="FirstCategory">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="One">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="UserName"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Password"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Two">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="UserName"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Password"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="SecondCategory">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="One">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="UserName"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Password"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Two">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="UserName"/>
                    <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Password"/>
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

the XML that really corresponds to the schema:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="XMLtoXSDValidation">
     <FirstCategory>
        <One>
          <UserName>a</UserName>
          <Password></Password>
        </One>
        <Two>
          <UserName>b</UserName>
          <Password></Password>
        </Two>
      </FirstCategory>
      <SecondCategory>
        <One>
          <UserName>a</UserName>
          <Password></Password>
        </One>
        <Two>
          <UserName>b</UserName>
          <Password></Password>
        </Two>
      </SecondCategory> 
    </root>
```

and here is the XML that claims to successfully validate:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Author>V-PC\V</Author>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <TimeTrigger>
      <StartBoundary>2014-03-16T17:27:02</StartBoundary>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </TimeTrigger>
    <LogonTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    </LogonTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>StopExisting</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>false</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>true</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>false</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>false</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>P3D</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
    <RestartOnFailure>
      <Interval>PT5M</Interval>
      <Count>3</Count>
    </RestartOnFailure>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is this part:

> The schema has a targetnamespace, which is not present in the "random" XML

Essentially, your schema has nothing to do with your XML file, so the validator can't make any judgement as to whether your file is valid or not.

If you add `ReportValidationWarnings` to [`XmlReaderSettings.ValidationFlags`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreadersettings.validationflags(v=vs.110).aspx), then you will get a warning to this effect:

> Warning:   Matching schema not found. No validation occurred. Could not find schema information for the element 'root'.

Comment: That indeed works... but it doesn't make sense to me.
This shouldn't be a warning. You shouldn't be warned that the XML is no where near being even close to the schema. It should be an error.

Comment: I second @BlueBunny, years later we still find that instead of a failed validation, the absence of a namespace seems to circumvent the validation process. Quite bizarre but the suggestion above at least provides a mechanism to ensure the application is aware that the submitted XML doesn't meet its expectations